# Combining two list python different sizes. Header list to data

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I used bs4 to collect sports data from Wikipedia. I was able to extract two lists: the stat headers list and the stats. I would like to recreate this df by combining the two lists. There are similar posts on SO but nothing that's exactly what I need. len(stat_header) = 13,  len(stats) = 195

I was able to create a dictionary but lost data in the process.
I tried converting to arrays but am still having trouble creating a df or concatenating because of the shape. I'm not getting that correct.

```
stat_header = ['Year','Team','GP','GS','MPG','FG%','3P%','FT%',
'RPG',APG',SPG','BPG','PPG']
```

```
# Just a sample 14 out of 195
stats = ['1984-85','Chicago','82','82','38.3','.515','.173',
'.845','6.5', '5.9','2.4','.8','28.2','1985–86',
```

This works but I'm missing a lot of data (most of the team names)

```
result = {v: stat_header[i % len(stat_header)]  
          for i, v in enumerate(stats)} 
print("resultant dictionary : ", str(result))
```

Reshaping (Doesn't work, just shape error)

```
x = np.reshape(stats, (15, 13))
y = np.reshape(stat_header, (1, 13)) 
pd.DataFrame(x, columns=y)
And this...
np.concatenate( ( np.fromstring( y, dtype=np.uint8 ), x ), axis=0 )
```

I've found and extracted the right information. I would like to put it back together again hopefully in a df.

Comment: Have you looked into pandas? pandas has pd.read_html() 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just replicate the contents of `stat_header`

```
stat_header = ['Year','Team','GP','GS','MPG','FG%','3P%','FT%',
'RPG','APG','SPG','BPG','PPG']

stats = ['1984-85','Chicago','82','82','38.3','.515','.173',
'.845','6.5', '5.9','2.4','.8','28.2','1985–86',..]

stat_header = stat_header * (len(stats)//len(stat_header))
```

Then use zip to construct the dict

```
result = list(zip(stats,stat_header))
```

Result will be:

```
[('1984-85', 'Year'), ('Chicago', 'Team'), ('82', 'GP'), ('82', 'GS'), ('38.3', 'MPG'), ('.515', 'FG%'), ('.173', '3P%'), ('.845', 'FT%'), ('6.5', 'RPG'), ('5.9', 'APG'), ('2.4', 'SPG'), ('.8', 'BPG'), ('28.2', 'PPG')]
```

Comment: I've used this option but it doesn't work for the full list. 
result will be exactly what you showed but the other values in stats will never be assigned a key.

Comment: @Cam updated the answer. Making it into a tuple will keep the values intact

Comment: I've seen this option in other threads here on SO. 
the output for results is:
```

{'1984–85': 'Year',
 'Chicago': 'Team',
 '82': 'GS',
 '38.3': 'MPG',
 '.515': 'FG%',
 '.173': '3P%',
 '.845': 'FT%',
 '6.5': 'RPG',
 '5.9': 'APG',
 '2.4': 'SPG',
 '.8': 'BPG',
 '28.2': 'PPG'}
```
basically I'm missing the 14 other seasons.

It only zip's the length of the stat_header list

Comment: Make sure you have `stat_header = stat_header * (len(stats)//len(stat_header))` this line included